# Javascript bypass current local date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I was wondering if there is a way to not get the local current date but the actual current date so that a user is not able to manipulate the date by changing the date in his OS's settings.

Currently I am using this to get the current date:

```js
var todaysDate = new Date();
$('#text').text(todaysDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: API call to the server?

Comment: I am not that good in server stuff. Any ideas/suggestions how to do so?

Comment: the server `time.akamai.com` makes it easy - see https://developer.akamai.com/stuff/Akamai_Time_Reference/AkamaiTimeReference.html

Comment: given that `you can NEVER trust the client computer` - the only way is to use the time of **your server** ... unless you can supply at least some information about it (i.e. what server side languages do you have access to) you wont get much help

Comment: Just to clarify even further - even if you send the date from your own server, you can still not trust the client. The user can still intercept and manipulate the data. For example, say you have a web shop and a promotional code expires at midnight, you have to verify this on your _server_. You could send the date and verify it in the browser for convenience of the user, but you can not rely on it for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a simple script that works in modern browsers

```js
function getTime(cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '//time.akamai.com/?iso');
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
        cb(new Date(xhr.responseText));
    });
    xhr.send();
}
function timeCB(time) {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "the time is " + time.toString();
}
getTime(timeCB);
```

```html
<div id='time'></div>
```

Comment: @Yanlu This is great, but remember that you can NEVER trust the client computer. An attacker could relatively easily set up his/her own server with a cloned date API, point time.akamai.com to that server throug the hosts file and thus manipulate the date anyway. If you need security and cannot trust the client, you _have_ to do this on a computer that _you_ control.

Comment: didn't think about that :p too bad using the IP address of time.akamai.com wont work for this